# Why is Community Bot calling perfectly good answers unclear?

Tags: discussion

What triggers this message

> As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –
> Community
> Bot

I've seen this several times recently. As in the case of this answer [ln: failed to create symbolic link "Function not implemented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178797/ln-failed-to-create-symbolic-link-function-not-implemented/1377300#1377300) -- I don't know if the answer is right or wrong, I didn't try it, but it isn't "unclear" in the slightest, and this comment is not helpful.

Comment: The bot is 'hiding' comments from some reviewers - those comments are being done by reviewers, not an automated bot.  It's a 'recent' change, but it's a much disliked one by moderators.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the info. I can see why it's disliked.

Comment: @muru the suggested duplicate refers to a (equally wrong-headed) bot comment on questions. This is about answers. But OK.