# Please consider not leaving feedback as Community♦

Tags: discussion, comments, review

Thanks for reviewing. I really appreciate it.

Recently review got reformatted quite a lot. Personally, I don't like many of the changes. I guess I'm an old stick-in-the-mud. But about one feature in particular, I think my feelings are correct. I'm talking about the **Leave Feedback** option that, for some reason I will never understand, allows you to pretend to be Community♦ (although instead of having a diamond, it is now labelled **bot**).

We've already had a couple of complaints about these comments here on meta

- [Why is Community Bot calling perfectly good answers unclear?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19833/why-is-community-bot-calling-perfectly-good-answers-unclear)
- [Out of context comments from the community bot](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19811/out-of-context-comments-from-the-community-bot)

and people have said they feel the feature is being misused. My feeling is that the problem is not with the users of the feature but with the feature itself. There is no way to use this feature that I would be okay with.

The comments from Community[bot] can't be meaningfully replied to. They take away accountability from the reviewer. Even if the comment is relevant (they rarely seem to be), this turns review into a throwaway task.

So since I feel I can't ask for this feature to be removed just yet, I'm asking y'all to think about not using it, as a personal favour. :) <3

I need to be clear on this: I have no right to stop y'all from using it. I promise I won't yell at anyone for using it. This isn't a rule I'm arbitrarily and unilaterally making. I'm just asking y'all to think about whether you really want to leave a comment pretending to be Community, or whether it would be more respectful and welcoming, and more useful, to leave a comment as yourself.

Thanks a lot, friends :)

Comment: "So since I feel I can't ask for this feature to be removed just yet": why not? Has anyone asked for this to be rolled back on MSE yet?

Comment: Well @terdon a lot of people objected to it at the time and there were [some modifications but really a doubling down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues). Other than in answers there I don't know if anyone has asked for it to be completely rolled back. Sometimes I feel like MSE is another planet. Anyway, personally I'm just not ready to raise the battle; the time doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: SE answers to SO. The rest of take whatever they shovel us.

Comment: Hi, @Paul! SO mod here. Unfortunately, what you say is not true. I absolutely *despise* this feature, as do many other moderators and power-users on SO, but we can't get it gone, either. I am not sure who SE answers to, but I know it's *definitely* not SO.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe they are using it to divide us so we fight against one another?

Comment: Hi Zanna. I wholeheartedly agree. Always consider customizing the comment to make it more relevant, and tick the box to review as yourself. This wasn't an option in the beginning, but it is now. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild yeah... I don't think those comments are any good. I write all my own comments even though on NAAs many of them are the same. I don't like the smell of can.

Comment: I believe the intention with the revised reviews were good, but the ones designing it didn't really get proper feedback before it went live.

Comment: You can reply to community by flagging the comment as "something else" and then using the comment section of the flag to reply but I guess that really doesn't solve the overall problem and it's not really a direct reply.

Comment: @mchid yeah the person who posted the feedback won't see that (unless they are a mod hahaha)

Comment: @mchid We cannot flag a Community bot comment as *Something else*.  It can only be flagged as *It's no longer needed.* https://i.stack.imgur.com/PorPw.png

Comment: This is a another really terrible example https://askubuntu.com/q/1379955/243321

Comment: [Here's a screenshot of that example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1wi1.png), since I'm removing that comment now!